# How to get onclick value in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say, that I have on my site something like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="lol(222)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(223)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(212)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(122)">
```

And then I would like to parse it to get in the `match` variable all values in `lol()`

Like this:

```
match[0] = 222;
match[1] = 223;
.....
```

Answer (score 6):

The most cross browser approach is to use `getAttributeNode`, because jQuery's `attr` will [have problems with IE7 and older](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9102):

```
var match = $("a[onclick]").map(function () {
    var onclick = this.getAttributeNode("onclick").nodeValue;
    return +onclick.slice(4, -1); 
}).get();
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Z2G2Z/**

Comment: Yet another reason why not to use inline Javascript +1

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but i think this can be solution:

```
<a href="" onclick="lol(this,222)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(this,223)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(this,212)">
<a href="" onclick="lol(this,122)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function lol(sender,value) {
    //sender is clicked item
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is a regular expression: http://jsfiddle.net/wtwzd/1/

```
var matches = [];
$('a').each(function() {
    matches.push(
        /lol\(([\d]+)\)/g
        .exec(
             $(this).attr('onclick')
        )[1]
    );
});
alert(matches);
```